# Special file compile in Linux kernel module makefile - ".o needed by stop" error

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, linux-kernel

I have a kernel module in which I would like to include a special file. The file is an ASM file. Nothing special about that, but yet it does not work.
The make error is:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/idou/Documents/badpervisor/driver/cpuid_available.o', needed by '/home/idou/Documents/badpervisor/hypervisor.o'.  Stop.
```

Kbuild:

```
obj-m := hypervisor.o

hypervisor-y := driver/entry.o \
                    driver/cpu_checks.o \
                driver/cpuid_available.o \

$(obj)/cpuid_available.o:
        nasm -f elf64 -o $(obj)/cpuid_available.o $(src)/cpuid_available.asm
```

Asm file:

```
section .text
            global is_cpuid_available
            
is_cpuid_available:
    pushfq                               ;
    pushfq                               ;
    xor dword [esp],0x00200000        ;
    popfq                                ;
    pushfq                               ;
    pop rax                              ;
    xor eax,[esp]                        ;
    popfq                                ;
    and eax,0x00200000                   ;
    ret
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `\ ` on the end of this line `driver/cpuid_available.o \ ` so it appears as `driver/cpuid_available.o` since it is the last file in the list and you don't want a line continuation character there.

Comment: Just for the record, that code is doomed.  RAX, and `pushf` with 64-bit operand-size (`q` suffix) are only available in 64-bit mode.  1. x86-64 guarantees that CPUID is available so you can just return true.  Only 32-bit mode needs to check; see GCC's `cpuid.h`'s ifdefs for example.  2. `[esp]` is uses only the low 32 bits of the stack pointer address RSP. In kernel code, even if that address happens to be mapped by user-space (which owns the low half of addr space), SMAP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor_Mode_Access_Prevention) will make sure it faults instead of accessing wrong data.

Comment: From the message I would say it expects to have a rule to build `$(obj)/driver/cpuid_available.o`, not `$(obj)/cpuid_available.o`.